# Desktop Freezes every few min

Tags: 14.04

Ever so often on Ubuntu 14.04 my desktop freezes. The mouse stops moving and nothing moves. However the sound keeps going and processes in the terminal keep going (although I can't see their progress).

To get my system working I have to go to ctrl alt f2 and then switch back using ctrl alt f7. This usually does the trick and everything resumes like nothing ever happened.

This has happened after a fresh install and continued since then. I expected it to go away after I performed all my updates- but it has not.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with a nvidia graphics card. (I'm using Nvidia's drivers).

Note that this appears to be the same probalem as [Ubuntu 14.04 Screen Freezes Randomly with NVidia and it is possible to fix with Ctrl + Alt + F2 then Ctrl + Alt + F7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519854/ubuntu-14-04-screen-freezes-randomly-nvidia) but there has been no solution that works posted yet.

Has anyone ran into this issue- know of any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally stumbled on the fix. I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 and it works. I'm not using the NVidia proprietary drivers (I was before).

I'm happy to provide more information upon request.