# Ubuntu 14.04 Display Freezes Occasionally

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, freeze

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. I have an NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M (1GB) graphics card, and I noticed the open source Nouveau display driver was returning error code -16 on suspend, causing the computer to immediately rewake. So I switched over to the proprietary, tested NVIDIA v331.38 driver.

This fixed the suspend problem, but now the display will occassionally freeze and stop accepting input. The computer itself doesn't freeze -- audio keeps playing and touchpad input still goes through.

For some reason, when I switch over to the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then switch back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, the display unfreezes and everything's fine until the next freeze.

It seems the freezing happens more often if I'm using my touchpad more actively. It's only brought on by a touchpad input as well. It won't freeze on its own.

Comment: FWIW, I have the exact same problem with v346.46.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Screen Freezes Randomly NVidia](http://askubuntu.com/questions/519854/ubuntu-14-04-screen-freezes-randomly-nvidia)

Comment: I experience very similar problems, but I'm using radeon driver with AMD Radeon HD3300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by switching over to the legacy driver - version 304.117 from nvidia-304-updates.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance, are you using a touch pad? If so, changing the touch pad to work as a normal usb mouse will correct issues with a 'unresponsive screen.' Unfortunately, you will not be allowed to use the tap to click feature or scroll using the pad.

Comment: I do have a touchpad, but if it will disable scrolling, this is not a workable solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. Fortunately, there is a fix now (but you'll need to compile packages yourself). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1220426.

Answer (score 0):

Check the additional drivers on control panel > Software & Updates. Choose the proprietary driver.

After, enter on terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and perform:

```
sudo depmod nouveau
sudo rmmod nouveau
sudo update-initramfs
```

Reboot the system.

Comment: I am already using the propriety driver, and the nouveau module is not loaded. Additionally, I believe the `depmod` command requires an absolute path to the module to generate dependencies for. Altogether this answer doesn't really do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with my 14.04 install. It would freeze for seemingly no particular reason. I blamed various pieces of software before realising it was the graphics drivers.

This post I found really useful in starting me on my journey to actually having working nvidia drivers.

[How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver)

Answer (score 0):

the following three BiOS settings ( 3 CMOS settings ) fixed it for
my ASUS M2N MX SE PLUS motherboard with
 AMD Athlon® 64-bit 2-core CPU 4200+ 
( and with NViDiA GeForce 6150SE graphics chip:)

---

❶   CPU clock = 200 MHz "manual" ( Not "Auto"; not "Limit" )

❷   4 GB RAM clock = 200 MHz "manual" ( Not "Auto"; not "Limit" )

❸   PCi express clock = 100 MHz "manual" ( Not "Auto"; not "Limit" )

---

with above setting, AMD 64-bit 2-core CPU runs at 2.21 GHz speed ( else if the BiOS CMOS setting is

either "Auto"

or "Limit = 250 MHz"  or  "Limit = 275 MHz"

then it may be randomly varying the clock speeds during run-time i guess ( also known as Spread-Spectrum-Clocking...